# What is "jubilee(s)"?

Tags: heaven, terminology, mosaic-law, jubilee

My Mother in her 90s and in treatment for Alzheimers would frequently go into a state of trance and chant about going to jubilee.

Does "jubilee" or "going to jubilee" refer to heaven or eternity in Christianity?

Answer (score 7):

In the Hebrew Bible, Jubilee refers to a set of practices around forgiveness of debts and restoration of land. Basically, every 7 years the people were supposed to hold a "sabbath" for the land and rest from farming. Then in the 50th year (the year after the 7th Sabbath/Sabbatical Year), all land ownership was supposed to resort to it's original tribes/clans/families, all debts be forgiven, all slaves set free, and a general year of celebration and festivity observed. This was known as the "Jubilee Year." See [Leviticus 25](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Leviticus%2025&version=NRSV) for a description of how this was supposed to work.

It's not originally a description of heaven, but it's an image a lot of later Biblical writers would use to describe "heaven" or "the kingdom" or "salvation" and other similar concepts. For example, [Isaiah 61](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%2061&version=NRSV) talks about the deliverance of the people by God as the "year of the Lord's favor" when the captives are set free, the cities rebuilt, and the people are too busy celebrating to tend their own flocks, which sounds a lot like the Jubilee year. So Jubilee takes on more meaning as an image of what heaven is supposed to be like.

Comment: Nice first answer.  I hope to read more of your work in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**[image: THE JUBILEES ARE HIDDEN IN THE LAWS OF PURIFICATION]**

### The Jubilee is a year of absolute liberty for mankind

From E-Sword Strong's Concordance: H3104 - יבל / יובל - yôbêl

#### BDB Definition:

1) ram, ram’s horn, trumpet, cornet

1a) ram (only in combination)

1a1) ram’s horn, trumpet

1b) jubilee year (marked by the blowing of cornets) (metonymy)

#### Excerpts from Fausset

The 50th Jubilee, after seven weeks of years, when alienated lands returned to the original owners and Hebrew bondservants were freed (Lev 25:8-16; Lev 25:23-55; Lev 27:16-25; Num 36:4).

It is referred to as antitypically fulfilled in "the acceptable year of the Lord," this limited period of gospel grace in which deliverance from sin and death, and the restoration of man's lost inheritance, are proclaimed through Christ (Isa 61:1-2; Luk 4:19). Literally, hereafter (Eze 7:12-13; Eze 46:17) to be kept. Liberty to bondservants was given every seventh or sabbatical year.

**"The times of the restitution of all things" are the coming grand Jubilee (Act 3:21), "the regeneration" (Mat 19:28) ushered in by "the trump of God" (1Th 4:16-17). The Spirit is meantime "the earnest of our inheritance until the redemption of the purchased possession" (Eph 1:13-14; Rom 8:19-23).**

---

In the image, the female seed is the Old Covenant or the literal understanding of the law. Under the New Covenant, the male seed is Christ or the spiritual and prophetic understanding and application of the Mosaic Law.

A Jubilee is the equivalent of 50 years. The Jubilee speaks of the removal of debt (sin). Under the Old Covenant, *every slave had to be freed from all their debts or wrongdoings*.

> Lev 25:10  And ye shall sanctify the fiftieth year and proclaim
>   liberty throughout all the land unto all the inhabitants thereof; it
>   shall be a jubilee unto you, and ye shall return every one unto his
>   possession, and ye shall return each one unto his family.
>
> Lev 25:11  A jubilee shall that fiftieth year be unto you; ye shall
>   not sow nor reap that which grows of itself in it nor fence in thy
>   consecrated vine.
>
> Psa 5:11  And all those that put their trust in thee shall rejoice:
>   they shall ever be in jubilee, for thou shalt cover them; and all that
>   love thy name shall be joyful in thee.

---

#### Excerpts From the Temple: It's Ministries - The Day of Atonement

In connection with this point, it may also be well to remember that the Jubilee Year was always proclaimed on the Day of Atonement (Lev 25:9).

---

EXCERPTS FROM MATTHEW HENRY - Matthew 24:4-31

> [5.] That he shall send his angels with a great sound of a trumpet,
>   Mat 24:31. Note, First, The angels shall be attendants upon Christ at
>   his second coming; they are called his angels, which proves him to be
>   God, and Lord of the angels; they shall be obliged to wait upon him.
>   Secondly, These attendants shall be employed by him as officers of the
>   court in the judgment of that day; they are now ministering spirits
>   sent forth by him (Heb 1:14) and will be so then. Thirdly, Their
>   ministration will be ushered in with a great sound of a trumpet, to
>   awaken and alarm a sleeping world. This trumpet is spoken of, 1Co
>   15:52, and 1Th 4:16. At the giving of the law on Mount Sinai, the
>   sound of the trumpet was remarkably terrible (Exo 19:13, Exo 19:16);
>   but much more will it be so in the great day. By the law, trumpets
>   were to be sounded for the calling of assemblies (Num 10:2), in
>   praising God (Psa 81:3), in offering sacrifices (Num 10:10), and in
>   proclaiming the year of jubilee, Lev 25:9. Very fitly, therefore,
>   shall there be the sound of a trumpet at the last day, when the
>   general assembly shall be called when the praises of God shall be
>   gloriously celebrated, when sinners shall fall as sacrifices to divine
>   justice, and when the saints shall enter upon their eternal Jubilee.

Excerpts From Matthew Henry - Luke 4:14-30

> [3.] The acceptable year of the Lord, Luk 4:19. He came to let the
>   world know that the God whom they had offended was willing to be
>   reconciled to them and to accept of them upon new terms; that there
>   was yet a way of making their services acceptable to him; that there
>   is now a time of good will toward men. It alludes to the year of
>   release, or that of jubilee, which was an acceptable year to servants,
>   who were then set at liberty; to debtors, against whom all actions
>   then dropped; and to those who had mortgaged their lands, for then
>   they returned to them again. Christ came to sound the jubilee-trumpet,
>   and blessed were they that heard the joyful sound, Psa 89:15. It was
>   an acceptable time, for it was a day of salvation.

---

From E. W. Bullinger  - Ezekiel 46:17

> The year of liberty = the year of jubilee. Reference to Pentateuch
>   (Lev 25:10). App-92. This shows that this prophecy will, and must yet,
>   be literally fulfilled. Moreover, the jubilee occurred only twice in a
>   century.

Luke 4:19

The acceptable year = the welcome year. Either the Jubilee year (Lev 26:8-17) or on account of the Lord’s ministry commencing then.

Answer (score 0):

Many believe that mankind has been on this planet for almost 6000 years (6 Millenia). The 7th, or Jubilee, Millenium is right around the corner. That will be the time when the Messiah (and us with Him) will reign in righteousness for a thousand years on Earth. This is what she is refering to. That should make any believer happy! Even so come quickly, Lord Jesus!